# Am I missing any parameters using search_code() of PyGitHub?

Tags: python, github

I want to search GitHub for codes that include a specific keyword. Using Python, I'm trying to use PyGithub with search_code(), but it is not retrieving anything, am I missing any parameter for the method or something ?

```
    query = keyword + '+in:file'
    results = auth.search_code(query)

    # print results
    print(f'Found {results.totalCount} result(s)')

    results_list = []
    for repo in tqdm(range(0, results.totalCount)):
        try:
            results_list.append([results[repo].repository.name])
            time.sleep(2)
        except RateLimitExceededException:
            time.sleep(60)
            results_list.append([results[repo].repository.name])
```

I have included all libraries and authenticated the access token.
I am new to programming, so any help will be appreciated, thanks.